# jQuery slideDown with forms

Tags: jquery, slidedown

why the following code doesn't work? Under Opera it show just a black line for a second where the div should be, Under IE it shows div for 1 second, under FF nothing happens.

```
function showAdvanced(){
$("#advanced").slideDown("slow");
};

<div id="content">
  <form action="mycontrolleraddress" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="search_form" id="search_form">
  <input type="text" name="query" value="" style="width:300px;font-size:18pt;border-color:#0080FF;border-width:2px;border-style:solid;background-color:#F2F2F2;"  />  
  <a href="" onclick="showAdvanced();" style="font-size:8pt;font-color:blue;">Advanced options</a>
  <br/>
  <div id="advanced" style="position:relative;height:400px;">From: 
    <input type="text" name="date_from" value="" id="datepicker" onchange="validateDate();" class="datefield"  /> To: 
    <input type="text" name="date_to" value="" id="datepicker2" onchange="validateDate();" class="datefield"  /> 
    <input type="text" name="limit" value="Results limit"  />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Szukaj"  />           
</div>
```

It's basically a textbox for search query, and I want advanced options (two data pickers and textbox) to appear after clicking a link.

Answer (score 0):

Is your script inside `<script>` tags, in `<head>`? Make sure it looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bJQVa/. Note that I also set #advanced to be hidden by default.

NOTE: I also added a # for the href and a return false in the function.

Comment: Yes it's in <head>, jQuery for the datapickers works fine. I've also got $("#advanced").hide(); on document load.

Comment: Does my jsFiddle work for you in FF? Works for me in 4.0.1, and also in IE 8.

Comment: NOTE: I also added a # for the href and a return false in the function.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't need to be head. I really was just checking for `<script>`. I'll edit.

Comment: I added 'return false;' in the function and now it works. Thx a bunch, Jed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        console.log('script loaded');

        function showAdvanced() {
            console.log('showAdvanced() executed');
            $("#advanced").slideDown("slow");
        };

        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('document is ready');
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
<form action="mycontrolleraddress" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="search_form" id="search_form">

<input type="text" name="query" value=""/><br/>

<a href="#" onclick="showAdvanced();" style="font-size:8pt;font-color:blue;">Advanced options</a><br/>

<div id="advanced" style="display: none;">
    From: <input type="text" name="date_from" value="" id="datepicker" onchange="validateDate();" class="datefield"  /><br/>
    To: <input type="text" name="date_to" value="" id="datepicker2" onchange="validateDate();" class="datefield"  /> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="limit" value="Results limit"  />
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Szukaj"  />

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Working for me. Next time try to format your code better, so it will be more readable.