# JQuery SlideDown on KeyPress

Tags: jquery, keypress, slidedown

I have a form with advanced options. The advanced options are in a div (hidden). When the "Search" input box is keyed I'd like to un-hide the div using slidedown. Here's the code (partially taken from another source: [jQuery slideDown with forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526725/jquery-slidedown-with-forms)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://api.jquery.com/resources/events.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#searched").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
        $("#advanced").slideDown();

});
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
<form action="mycontrolleraddress" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="search_form" id="search_form">

<input type="text" name="query" value="" placeholder="Search..." id="searched"/><br/>

<div id="advanced" style="display: none;">
    From: <input type="text" name="date_from" value="" id="datepicker" onchange="validateDate();" class="datefield"  /><br/>
    To: <input type="text" name="date_to" value="" id="datepicker2" onchange="validateDate();" class="datefield"  /> <br/>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

use inside `$(function() {});` or `$(document).ready(function() {});`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
$("#searched").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
        $("#advanced").slideDown();

});
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search_form').on('focus', '#searched', function(e){
    $('#advanced').slideDown();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to wrap your javascript code inside this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code
});
```